# Compute business days between two dates

Tags: r

New to R and learning lot and I love it.

My sales dataset has product, bpid, date. I would like to calculate the business difference between same bpid (just excluding Saturday & Sunday) .

If product or bpid changes (Or new bpid/product introduced), we need to skip the computations.

```
    df <- data.frame(product=c('milk','milk','milk','milk','eggs','eggs','eggs','eggs'), 
                     bpid=c(400,400,500,500,400,400,500,500),
                     date=c("2016-08-03","2016-08-10","2016-08-04","2016-08-10","2016-08-10","2016-08-16","2016-08-11","2016-08-15"));

df$date <- as.Date(df$date, format = "%Y-%m-%d");
```

My Desired result would be like below. **Please help....**

```
 product bpid       date    compute-result
   milk  400 2016-08-03      0
   milk  400 2016-08-10      5
   milk  500 2016-08-04      0
   milk  500 2016-08-10      5
   eggs  400 2016-08-10      0
   eggs  400 2016-08-16      4
   eggs  500 2016-08-11      0
   eggs  500 2016-08-15      2
```

Real Data code (getting zeros at result column)

```
df <- data.frame(product=c('Keyt','Keyt','Keyt','Keyt','Keyt','Keyt'), 
                 bpid=c(30057,30057,30057,30058,30058,30058),
                 date=c("2014-11-21","2015-05-05","2015-05-11","2014-10-16","2014-11-03","2016-03-15"));

df$date <- as.Date(df$date, format = "%Y-%m-%d");

cal <-  Calendar(weekdays=c("saturday", "sunday"))
df$`compute-result` <- 0
idx <- seq(1, nrow(df),2)
df$`compute-result`[idx+1] <- bizdays(df$date[idx], df$date[idx+1], cal)
df
```

Comment: Check out the `wday()` function in `lubridate`. That should help you get past a roadblock.

Comment: Also the [`bizdays`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bizdays/) package or the [`timeDate`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/timeDate/) package, which have functions for finding weekends and holidays.

Comment: You can use RQuantLib package to exclude all the holidays in the calendar

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For example:

```
# install.packages("bizdays")
library(bizdays)
cal <-  create.calendar(name = "mycal", weekdays=c("saturday", "sunday"))
df$`compute-result` <- 0
idx <- seq(1, nrow(df),2)
df$`compute-result`[idx+1] <- bizdays(df$date[idx], df$date[idx+1], cal)
df
#   product bpid       date compute-result
# 1    milk  400 2016-08-03              0
# 2    milk  400 2016-08-10              5
# 3    milk  500 2016-08-04              0
# 4    milk  500 2016-08-10              4
# 5    eggs  400 2016-08-10              0
# 6    eggs  400 2016-08-16              4
# 7    eggs  500 2016-08-11              0
# 8    eggs  500 2016-08-15              2
```

---

if you want to group by `product` and `bpid`, you could try

```
# install.packages("bizdays")
library(bizdays)
cal <-  create.calendar(name="mycal", weekdays=c("saturday", "sunday"))
with(df, ave(as.integer(date), product, bpid, FUN=function(x) { 
  x <- as.Date(x, origin="1970-01-01") 
  c(0, bizdays(head(x, -1), tail(x, -1), cal)) 
})) -> df$result
df
#   product  bpid       date result
# 1    Keyt 30057 2014-11-21      0
# 2    Keyt 30057 2015-05-05    117
# 3    Keyt 30057 2015-05-11      4
# 4    Keyt 30058 2014-10-16      0
# 5    Keyt 30058 2014-11-03     12
# 6    Keyt 30058 2016-03-15    356
```

Note that is converted `date` to `integer` and back to `Date` inside the function because otherwise `ave` throws an error:

> ```
> Error in as.Date.numeric(value) : 'origin' must be supplied
> and I dunno how to supply that origin argument here.
> ```

Comment: You are rockstar!! hank you. BTW, can you explain how your program is picking new bpid or product please? I am new and your explanation will help me in apply the same logic in other places.

Comment: I've abstracted from new products and bpids but just calculated thhe difference between 2-1, 4-3 etc

Comment: @ lukeA I am start experimenting on real data. But I am keep getting this error. Can you help me here please?    I appended my code to original post with heading .."Real Data".

Comment: @ luke or some help me here please? I posted question at the top again with 'Real Data Code'

Comment: @ lukeA ...that did the magic. Thank you, it is working now and no error.